# Powershell script to check if given hours is between working hours

Tags: powershell

What I've done is to get the current hour and then compare it to a string that I get as an output from a system that I split to get the starting hour and ending hour.

The check keeps showing up as True no matter what the time is

```
$current_day = Get-Date -Format "dddd"
$current_hour = Get-Date -Format "HH:mm"
$string = "Sat 16:00 to 00:00".Split(" ")
$day = $string[0]
$from_hour = Get-Date $string[1] -Format "HH:mm"
$to_hour = Get-Date $string[3] -Format "HH:mm"
Write-Output("CURRENT TIME: {0} {1}" -f $current_day, $current_hour)
Write-Output("GIVEN TIME: {0} from {1} to {2}" -f $string_day, $string_from_hour, $string_to_hour)
if($current_hour -le $from_hour -and $current_hour -ge $to_hour)
{
    return $true
}
else
{
    return $false
}
```

Comment: `$current_hour` is _always_ going to be greater than or equal to `00:00`

Comment: It's returning true because both conditions are in fact true. Certainly at the time you run it. As @MathiasR.Jessen said anything will be greater than 0.  However, why aren't you just comparing formal `[DateTime]` objects.   The way you are doing it you're comparing strings.  Since hours and minutes are quantities, I'm not sure how reliable that will be...

Answer (score 1):

Your code does work with just a few small changes.

The most critical is just swapping the operators around for your `if` statement

```
Write-Output("GIVEN TIME: {0} from {1} to {2}" -f $string_day, $from_hour, $to_hour)
if($current_hour -ge $from_hour -and $current_hour -le $to_hour)
```

Finally, instead of comparing to 00:00 midnight, change the end time to `23:59` which is close enough for government work. With these two things done, it works.

```
CURRENT TIME: Thursday 19:13
GIVEN TIME:  from 16:00 to 23:59
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$StartTime = "16:00";
$EndTime = "00:00"
$EndTime_ = (Get-Date $EndTime).AddDays(1);


if (((Get-Date) -gt (Get-Date $StartTime)) -and ((Get-Date) -lt ($EndTime_))) {
    Get-Date -Format "hh:mm";
}
else {
    $false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for their suggestions.
I couldn't miss a minute as the script is intended to run per hour.
So what I've done is to convert 00:00 into 99:99 (both current time and working hours) and it works flawlessly.